# Problem in working with a Master Project Plan and sub projects when they exists inside multiple documents libraries

Tags: 2013, document-library, office-integration, office, ms-project

I am working on a SharePoint on-premises 2013 farm. and i have a team site, with around 50 sub-sites. now under each sub-site there is a document library. and for all documents libraries they share the following settings:-

Advance settings:-

[image]

Versioning Settings:-

[image]

now our customer asked us that they need to be able to utilize the MS project tool to use Master and sub projects which require links between multiple files, where the master and its sub projects might exists on different document libraries..

Now when having the files on local drives (not sharepoint libraries), and they open the master project plan it automatically updates the sub project/s , but in sharepoint's document libraries it does not work. where opening a master plan and edit it will not affect its sub-projects.

now they mentioned that they can solve this issue by either:-

- specify a checkout location that can ensure all those that access this type of file uses
- or add a link to the project plan leaving it on a local drive.

now the problem i do not have MS project installed so i can not reproduce the case. So i am planning to send our customer a set of instruction to try .. but not sure what could be causing the above issues, when working with MS projects inside sharepoint doc libraries?? to me saving a file inside sharepoint doc library should not differ from having it saved locally...